# /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: gen_context.o: unknown type [0x20] section `'

Tags: 16.04, compiling, make

Are any members familiar with the error that I encounter when trying to compile Dash via the command `make` on Ubuntu 16.04

```
Making all in src

make[1]: Entering directory '/root/dash/src'

make[2]: Entering directory '/root/dash/src'

make[3]: Entering directory '/root/dash/src/secp256k1'


gcc gen_context.o -o gen_context
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: gen_context.o: unknown type [0x20] section `'
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: gen_context.o: unknown type [0x20] section `'
gen_context.o: file not recognized: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:1528: recipe for target 'gen_context' failed
make[3]: *** [gen_context] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/dash/src/secp256k1'
Makefile:9962: recipe for target 'secp256k1/libsecp256k1.la' failed
make[2]: *** [secp256k1/libsecp256k1.la] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/dash/src'
Makefile:9456: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/dash/src'
Makefile:657: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: It is unclear: 1. why you are compiling as root user? ; 2. what configure options do you use? ; 3. what build-dependencies have you installed? Please clarify these moments in the question.

Answer (score 1):

On my clean Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS I do not have any problems.

At first you need to install build-dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install git autoconf libtool-bin libdb++-dev qt5-default \
qt4-linguist-tools libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev \
libboost-test-dev  libevent-dev qttools5-dev-tools protobuf-compiler
```

Then clone repository, run configure and make:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/dashpay/dash.git
cd dash
./autogen.sh
./configure --with-incompatible-bdb
make -j4
```

Then test it (optionally):

```
src/test/test_dash
src/qt/test/test_dash-qt
```

And install to the system:

```
sudo make install
```